# how to return records with dates in array less than a particular date

Tags: php, mysql

To simplify, each record in a database has Company Name, the Total Spend and Nights reserved.  The Nights reserved are stored in the form of a string and then parsed later in the process.
example: `Customer`= "Bob's Heating" `Total`= 3000 `Reserved`= "1/2/2017,1/3/2017,1/5/2017..."

I need to write a query that selects all record whose reservations begin on or before a particular date, so if the target date was "1/4/2017" Bob Heating's record above would be returned.

Any help would be appreciated, 
Jim

Comment: `"stored in the form of a string and then parsed later in the process"` - Seems like "later in the process" would be when you'd make the comparison then.  You'd have to compare dates when they're dates, not when they're strings.  (Storing the dates as dates and not as strings would make things much easier.)

Comment: And store each date in its own row in a table that relates back to this one.  As you can see you haven't simplified but made your work more complex.

Comment: Can you provide sample code so that we can assist you?

Answer (score 0):

1.) Create a new table in your database called "reservation_dates" that has the columns: row_id (INT), the_date (DATE)

2.) Run a script in PHP that moves all of those dates into another table that stores them as DATE data types.

Example PHP script:

```
$statement = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $statement) or die(mysqli_error($con));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $dates = explode(",", $row['Reserved']);
    foreach($dates as $date)
       {
        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO reservation_dates (row_id, the_date) VALUES ('".$row['id']."', '$date')") or die(mysqli_error($con));
       }
    }
```

Run the PHP script. Now you will have all of your dates in a relational table called reservation_dates.

Next, to select all of the rows that fall within 1/4/2017, run a query such as

```
SELECT customer.* FROM reservation_dates reservation JOIN my_table customer ON customer.id = reservation.row_id WHERE MAX(reservation.the_date) >= '2017-04-01' AND MIN(reservation.the_date) <= '2017-04-01' GROUP BY row_id
```

I typed this quickly without actually trying the code but that's the general approach I would take. Hope it helps!